# Why won't my side-nav transition smoothly on closing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm following a tutorial by Brad Traversy called "Responsive HTML&CSS 
 side menu from scratch. I'm having an issue with the closing of the `side-nav`
 as it snaps instead of closing smoothly as in the video. Can someone 
 let me know what I have done wrong??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" 
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <span class="open-slide">
        <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
          <svg width="30" height="30">
            <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
            <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
            <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
          </svg>
        </a>
      </span>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
      <a href="" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">home</a>
      <a href="#">about</a>
      <a href="#">servoces</a>
      <a href="#">contact</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <h1>responsive side menu</h1>
    </div>

    <script>
      function openSlideMenu() {
        document.getElementById("side-menu").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
      }

      function closeSlideMenu() {
        document.getElementById("side-menu").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>






body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 63px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar ul {
  padding: 8px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #000;
}

.side-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  opacity: 0.9;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.side-nav a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.side-nav a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.side-nav .btn-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 22px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I expected for the side menu and the main content so slide to the left smoothly.

Comment: `instead of closing smoothly as in the video` what video?

Comment: The title of the video is in the first sentence. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't have an `#` on your href that was redirecting to an empty url on this line `<a href="" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>` added #

Snippet below

```js
function openSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById("side-menu").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById("side-menu").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 63px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar ul {
  padding: 8px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #000;
}

.side-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  opacity: 0.9;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.side-nav a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.side-nav a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.side-nav .btn-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 22px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <span class="open-slide">
        <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
          <svg width="30" height="30">
            <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
            <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
            <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
          </svg>
        </a>
      </span>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
    <a href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">home</a>
    <a href="#">about</a>
    <a href="#">servoces</a>
    <a href="#">contact</a>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <h1>responsive side menu</h1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You beat me to it! Just deleted my answer, which said basically the same thing. :-)

Comment: The name of the video is in the question. In the first sentence, actually.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.